# Can this nested set of integrals be evaluated?

Tags: calculus, integration

So, here's the integrals I'm looking at...

$$\int_0^n {1 \over x!} \, dx - {1 \over 2} \int_0^n \int_0^{n-x} {1 \over x!} \cdot {1 \over y!} \, dy \, dx+ {1 \over 3} \int_0^n \int_0^{n-x}\int_0^{n-x-y} {1 \over x!} \cdot {1 \over y!}\cdot {1 \over z!} \,dz \, dy \, dx - {1 \over 4}... $$

Can these be evaluated to anything?

As a point of comparison, I am fairly certain that the discrete analog,

$$\sum_{x=1}^n {1 \over x!} - {1 \over 2} \sum_{x=1}^n \sum_{y=1}^{n-x} {1 \over x!} \cdot {1 \over y!} + {1 \over 3} \sum_{x=1}^n \sum_{y=1}^{n-x}\sum_{z=1}^{n-x-y} {1 \over x!} \cdot {1 \over y!}\cdot {1 \over z!} - {1 \over 4}...$$

is always equal to 1 when $n$ is a whole number > 0.

Comment: You need to specify what you mean by $x!$ for non-integer $x$. Euler's Pi function?

Comment: Oh, sure, sorry.  I intended that to mean the factorial function generalized as the gamma function in the usual way, as $x!=\Gamma(x+1)$